# Does kale taste sweeter and more flavorful after being frozen?

Tags: freezing, vegetables

According to this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kale#Culinary_uses) it does.

However a chef at my restaurant had not heard of this.

The wikipedia article seems to be missing citations, and I don't have time to perform an experiment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have misread the Wikipedia quote. It says (emphasis added):

> Kale freezes well and actually *tastes sweeter and more flavourful after being exposed to a frost*.

While not terribly well written (since there is the red herring that it freezes well), this doesn't mean that the harvested plant was frozen, but rather that the live plant in the ground was exposed to frost.  This causes it to begin converting starches to sugars in preparation for winter, giving it a sweeter taste.

Per [Burpee](http://www.burpee.com/vegetables/kale/all-about-kale-article10234.html), for example:

> Frost enhances the flavor. Some of the tastiest kale is harvested
>   under a foot of snow! Never harvest kale until after a hard frost or
>   two. A few freezing nights make all the difference in flavor as the
>   kale plants need a hard frost to transform their starches into natural
>   sugars.

Comment: but are you sure that this transformation cannot happen after harvesting? It happens when refrigerating harvested potatoes IIRC, so why not in kale?

Comment: @rumtscho I am not 100% certain not being a biologist, but normally if a vegetable is frozen after harvesting, it is *left* that way, and that would essentially shut down its metabolic processes.  So I think this is a true inference in practice, even if there is some theoretical possibility the kale is harvested, frozen, thawed, and still not senescent and so continues starch to sugar conversion.

Comment: Parsnips are also sweeter after a frost, and I have picked, frozen, then used them to get the same effect

Answer (score 0):

I found this online. Doesn't say anything about freezing, but frost does it too. So, I would think frost makes it sweeter.

http://garden.lovetoknow.com/wiki/8_Frost_Resistant_Vegetables